# Python dictionary comprehension from file

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension, for-comprehension

I am trying to make everything in my python code with comprehension. I had to convert a .txt file data to dict. It looked like this:

```
A   .-
B   -...
C   -.-.
...
```

Yeah, it's morse code.

My code looks like this:

```
def morse_file_to_dict(filename):
    d = {}
    for line in open(filename):
        ch, sign = line.strip().split('\t')
        d[ch] = sign
    return d
```

It gives back a normal dict like this:

```
{'A': '.-', 'B': '-...', 'C': '-.-.', ... }
```

My question is, can i make this **in one line**? With **comprehension**?

Thank you for your time and answer!

Comment: it will be less readable as a comprehension. the way you have it now is just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function can become:

```py
def morse_file_to_dict(filename):
    with open(filename) as fh:    
        return dict(l.strip().split() for l in fh)
```

This takes advantage of creating a dict from tuples.

If there is a chance that there are more than two fields, you should use:

```py
def morse_file_to_dict(filename):
    with open(filename) as fh:    
        return dict(l.strip().split("\t", 1) for l in fh)
```

This second example specifically sets the `sep` and `maxsplit` parameters of [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split)

Answer (score 1):

Not a comprehension, but the shortest:

```
dict(map(str.split, open(filename)))
```

Generator fed to a dict

```
dict(kv.split() for kv in open(filename))
```

Dict comprehension will be messy, because you have no state to extract the split, so you must calculate it twice

```
{kv.split()[0]: kv.split()[1] for kv in open(filename)}
```

Comment: Yes, there is an implied `import string` for that one, apologies for any confusion.  Will update